# Spring application context file location in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am trying to figure out where to put the `spring application context XML` file (mapping Service Beans) in a `IntelliJ` generated `Spring MVC` template. If I put it in the `WEB-INF` folder, it complains when I import the XML in the `dispatcher servlet XML` file. If i put it in the webapp folder, tomcat complains that it can't find it in the `WEB-INF` folder. So where do I actually put it?

The template generated by `IntelliJ` for a `Spring MVC` application has a 'pages' folder inside `webapp dir`. Do I have to put my `jsps` there or in the `WEB-INF` folder as in Eclipse? How is the root context path mapped to this folder when deployed in `Tomcat`?

[image: spring application XML]

Answer (score 2):

In the *web.xml* you mention *contextConfigLocation* which mentions the locations and names of the resources which the context reads. This element should contain the path and name of the XML files.

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:com/some/path/applicationContext.xml classpath:dbContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Now the *dbcontext.xml* is directly under the classpath whereas applicationContext is in the classpath in the folder heirarchy com/some/path

When the application gets built, the classess generally go into *WEB-INF/classes* directory. So if a war is made with above config, dbContext will be under classes dir.
Generally, it could be a good idea to create another source folder in your project. Name it something like resources or config and put your configuration files there.

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it  in classpath and have the following configuration in web.xml

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
```

org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

In a maven project we are keeping it inside resources folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can put `spring-context` file in the same directory where `dispatcher-servlet` is exist or you can create new directory inside web-inf say spring in that you can put the `spring-context` file.

suppose you have put the `spring-context` inside `spring directory` then you can call it like :

```
<import resource="spring/spring-context.xml"/>
```

in `dispatcher-servlet.xml`.

look this is my structure of spring application and working great :

[image]

still some problem then post me.